# Getting error trying to retrieve newly created document data in widget build method

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to invoke a method in initState. This method creates a document inside a collection if it doesnt exist. Then I will use this newly created document in my widget build but whenever I hot restart the app it will come up with error before showing the data on the screen :

> ════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
> The following _CastError was thrown building FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>(dirty, state: _FutureBuilderState<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>>#50c6f):
> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast

this is my initstate code and my widget build code:

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _createUserTracking();
  }

Future<void> _createUserTracking() async {
    String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    CollectionReference usersCollection =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Tracking Progress');

    DocumentSnapshot userSnapshot = await usersCollection.doc(uid).get();

    if (!userSnapshot.exists) {
      await usersCollection.doc(uid).set({
        'intTotalProgress': 0.7,
        'stringTotalProgress': '70%',
        'intOralHygienePractices': 0.8,
        'stringOralHygienePractices': '80%',
        'intCommonOralProblems': 0.7,
        'stringCommonOralProblems': '70%',
        'intPreventiveMeasures': 0.6,
        'stringPreventiveMeasures': '60%',
        'intVRContent': 0.4,
        'stringVRContent': '40%',
      });
    }
  }

 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? uid = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.uid;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('Tracking Progress')
              .doc(uid)
              .get(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!.exists) {
              Map data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map;
              return Column();
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: From the error message it looks like the document doesn't exist, or it doesn't contain any data, despite you checking for that on the line above the `as Map` cast. 

Comment: I actually just recently add snapshot.data!.exists and it turns out that the document doesnt exist but when i check in the firebase the document already been created, this problem only occurs for the first time reload and after that it works fine, its really confusing

Comment: You're trying to complete a future within the initState.  That's not possible, as initState is sync only, not async, and needs to execute rather quickly. The best you can do is *start* to create the doc in initState, then hold the future in state and use a FutureBuilder in your build(), which must start immediately.